# Request and Http Work on Postman but fails in Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, http-headers

I have the following code:

```
import http.client

conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("www.williams-sonoma.com")
payload = ''
headers = {
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/118.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
'Cookie': '<some value here>'}

conn.request("GET", "/api/catalog/v1/catalogobjects/query/?skuId=8739781", payload, headers)
res = conn.getresponse()
data = res.read()
print(data.decode("utf-8"))
```

Post Man generates:

[{"id":"glass-prep-bowl-8-piece-set","imageUrl":"https://assets.wsimgs.com/wsimgs/rk/images/dp/wcm/202340/0374/img40t.jpg","name":"Glass
Prep Mixing Bowls, Set of
8","salePriceMax":34.95,"salePriceMin":34.95,"regularPriceMax":24.95,"regularPriceMin":24.95,"skuId":"8739781","available":true,"sellable":true}]

I get the following in python:

`b'<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\n<head>\n    <title>Williams-Sonoma: 403 - Restricted Access</title>\n    <meta charset="utf-8" />\n    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/netstorage/css/common.css" type="text/css" media="all" />\n    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/netstorage/css/errors.css" type="text/css" media="all" />\n</head>\n\n<body>\n    <div class="error-container">\n        <img src="/netstorage/images/logo-ws.png" alt="Williams-Sonoma" />\n        <p>Sorry, due to website restrictions we are unable to display the requested page.</p>\n    </div>\n\n<!-- Analytics -->\n    <script type="text/javascript">\n      window.digitalData = {\n        page: {\n          pageName: "Restricted Access Error",\n          attributes: {\n            cmPageId : "Restricted Access Error",\n            cmCategoryId : "ERROR"\n          },\n          pageCategory: {\n            primaryCategory: "error"\n          }\n        }\n      };\n      var utag_data = {};\n      (function(a,b,c,d){\n          a=\'//tags.tiqcdn.com/utag/wsi/williamssonoma/prod/utag.js\';\n          b=document;c=\'script\';d=b.createElement(c);\n          d.src=a;\n          d.type=\'text/java\'+c;\n          d.async=true;\n          a=b.getElementsByTagName(c)[0];\n          a.parentNode.insertBefore(d,a);\n      })();\n    </script>\n<!-- end Analytics -->\n</body>\n</html>\n'`

How to overcome this problem? I've looked into similar answers but none seem to work. Btw way this is my 2-3rd attempt only.

I want to get the same response as Postman for Python.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an error:

cmPageId : "Restricted Access Error"

Are you behind a corporate proxy? Try setting the proxies field to force the script to make a direct connection:

```
import http.client

# Set up the connection without using a proxy
conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("www.williams-sonoma.com", proxies={})

payload = ''
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/118.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
    'Cookie': '<some value here>'
}

conn.request("GET", "/api/catalog/v1/catalogobjects/query/?skuId=8739781", payload, headers)
res = conn.getresponse()
data = res.read()
print(data.decode("utf-8"))
```

Comment: Nope, I believe proxies can only be used with requests? I did try that but still getting 403: Restricted Access error

Comment: If you use requests lib you need to create a session and then set `session.trust_env = False` to bypass proxy